# Comparing value of one column with different rules defined in a column of another table

Tags: sql

I have to compare value of a column with different rules defined in a column of another table to find if it is a dummy record or not.

```
table 1 :                       table 2:
Company Name                    Dummy word:
ABC corp                        %Invalid%
Company                         Company
Invalid                         No%Value%
NO Value
```

based on the table 2 rules, I have to decide if the value in table 1 is valid or not

Comment: Can you edit your question adding an example of how this comparison should be done?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?